# setting array in Solidity

Tags: solidity

consider the following solidity pseudo-code:

```
contract Test{


  bytes ar;

  function set_a(bytes val) external{

  //(1) ar = val;

 //(2) for (uint i=0;i < val.length;i++) ar[i] = val[i];

   }
}
```

**Question**: Which one the above two approaches is recommended (1 or 2)?

Answer (score 1):

> I think the first approach is right! why?

As writing smart contract we take care of gas cost and do optimize code for low gas price cost.
if you use the second approach where too many operations are there like less then, GT, assignment, and increment which cost more then the first approach.

you can see here:

```
Operation         Gas           Description

ADD/SUB           3             Arithmetic operation
MUL/DIV           5             Arithmetic operation
ADDMOD/MULMOD     8             Arithmetic operation
AND/OR/XOR        3             Bitwise logic operation
LT/GT/SLT/SGT/EQ  3             Comparison operation
POP               2             Stack operation 
PUSH/DUP/SWAP     3             Stack operation
MLOAD/MSTORE      3             Memory operation
JUMP              8             Unconditional jump
JUMPI             10            Conditional jump
SLOAD             200           Storage operation
SSTORE            5,000/20,000  Storage operation
BALANCE           400           Get balance of an account
CREATE            32,000        Create a new account using CREATE
CALL              25,000        Create a new account using CALL
```